# Textarea return empty alert , i use all thy way by name ,class , id , but still empty alert in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<textarea name="comt_graph" id="coment_group_value"
    rows="5" style="width:275px; border:1px solid #D6403F;"></textarea>
```

and jquery code is

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('.group_coment').live('click',function (){
        var coment_val = $('#coment_group_value').val();
        alert(coment_val);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: hi you are use the class **group_coment** . but where is class ?

Comment: are you put the class name or not ?

Comment: group_coment is a class of button , i want the value of texarea on click of buton.

Comment: its working here http://jsfiddle.net/drGt7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi i check it in js fiddle but it work fine for me

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/sXTRF/)

Are you use the developing tools for this ?
your code is working...

**Error script in another place can make you code stopped working. Try to check your syntax**

Answer (score 1):

From the code you've provided, there is no `group_coment` class in your HTML.

Either:

- add `class="group_coment"` to your `textarea` element, or
- change the jQuery selector; replace `.group_coment` with `#coment_group_value`

Or, if this is the only `textarea` element on the page, you could replace `.group_coment` with `textarea`.

Comment: group_coment is a class of image , i want the value of texarea on click of such image

Comment: Add `<img class="group_coment" src="foo.jpg" />` to your HTML then, and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no group_coment class in your HTML. Either provide a class in HTMl or write this code for check the value of the textarea.

`$(document).ready(function (){

```
    var coment_val = $('#coment_group_value').val();
    alert(coment_val);
```

});`

Comment: group_coment is a class of image , i want the value of textarea on click of such image